# How to widen tabu table in landscape?

Tags: tables, landscape, tabu

I have a wide table in a document. So I am using `landscape` to cover the table. The table has been created using `tabu`. I am getting the following result:[image]

with the input attached at the end of the question. I am trying to obtain a table where the table is spread over the whole width. I am using `X` column of `tabu` which works great in portrait mode. How can I make it in landscape mode to look my table nicer?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

Some content

\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
    \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
        \centering % Center table
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X[m,c]X[m,c]X[m,c]X[m,c]X[m,c]X[m,c]}
 & Magnitude (in terms of quantum  number $l, s,$ or $j$) & Possible values  it can get for one orientation  $(m_{l}, m_s,$ or $m_j$) & Magnetic moment (vector) & Magnetic moment (magnitude) & g-factor \\ 
 
Orbital Angular Momentum $(\vb{L})$   &  $|\vb{L}|=\sqrt{l(l+1)}\hbar$  &  $-l, -l+1, \ldots, l$   &  $\mu_{\vb{l}}=-g_o\frac{e}{2m_e}\vb{l}$   &   $g_o\mu_B\sqrt{l(l+1)}$     &    1     \\ 

Spin Angular Momentum $(\vb{S})$  & $|\vb{S}|=\sqrt{s(s+1)}\hbar$    &   $-s, -s+1, \ldots, s$    &  $\mu_{\vb{s}}=-g_s\frac{e}{2m_e}\vb{s}$      & $g_s\mu_B\sqrt{s(s+1)}$  &     2    \\ 

Total Angular Momentum $(\vb{J}=\vb{L}+\vb{S})$ & $|\vb{J}|=\sqrt{j(j+1)}\hbar$ &  $-j, -j+1, \ldots, j$ & $\mu_{\vb{s}}=-g\frac{e}{2m_e}\vb{j}$    & $g\mu_B\sqrt{j(j+1)}$    &     \\ 
\end{tabu}
    \end{landscape}
    \clearpage% Flush page
}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Following DavidCarisle's comment and changing

```
\textwidth{X[m,c]X[m,c]X[m,c]X[m,c]X[m,c]X[m,c]}
```

to

```
\linewidth{X[3c]X[3m,c]X[3m,c]X[3m,c]X[2m,c]X[2m,c]}
```

gives a better look. But I am still looking for a solution, if possible, to widen the table over full landscape width.
[image]

Comment: tabu does not really work with current latex (and is not maintained) but you could use `\linewidth` in place of `\textwidth`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it makes the table a little better but not to the extent I was looking for. I played with the parameters and it gives much better result (see the edited question). However, I don't understand how to spread the table over full width.

Comment: `{tabu} to 25cm`   or whatever size you want

Comment: `tabu` was dis-recommended, though I don't know if that's still the case. There are better packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware that in `landscape` orientation the width of the text block is equal to `\textheight`. If you determine width of table by `\linewidth`, it will for width of table use `\textheight`.

As already mentioned in comments, don9t use `tabu` package, rather use `tabularx` or even better `tabularray` which among others consider many features of `tabu`.

Possible MWE, using `tblr` of `tabularray` package and a wee bit redesign of table, can be:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

Some content

\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
    \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page 
\mbox{}\vfil    % for move table to vertical center of landscape oriented page
\begin{tblr}{colsep  = 4pt,
             colspec = {@{} X[l,m] 
                            X[0.9, c, m,  mode=math]
                            X[1.2, c, m,  mode=math] 
                       *{2}{X[0.9, c, m, mode=math]}
                            Q[c] @{}},
             row{1}  = {font=\small, mode=text, f}
              }
    \toprule
    & Magnitude (in terms of quantum  number $l, s,$ or $j$) 
        & Possible values  it can get for one orientation  $(m_{l}, m_s,$ or $m_j$) 
            & Magnetic moment (vector) 
                & Magnetic moment (magnitude) 
                    & {g\\ factor} \\
    \midrule
Orbital Angular Momentum $(\vb{L})$   
    & \abs{\vb{L}}=\sqrt{l(l+1)}\hbar  
        & -l, -l+1, \ldots, l   
            & \mu_{\vb{l}}=-g_o\frac{e}{2m_e}\vb{l}    
                & g_o\mu_B\sqrt{l(l+1)}     
                    &    1     \\
Spin Angular Momentum $(\vb{S})$  
    &  \abs{\vb{S}}=\sqrt{s(s+1)}\hbar    
        & -s, -s+1, \ldots, s   
            &  \mu_{\vb{s}}=-g_s\frac{e}{2m_e}\vb{s}      
                & g_s\mu_B\sqrt{s(s+1)}   
                    &     2    \\
Total Angular Momentum $(\vb{J}=\vb{L}+\vb{S})$ 
    & \abs{\vb{J}}=\sqrt{j(j+1)}\hbar 
        & -j, -j+1, \ldots, j 
            & \mu_{\vb{s}}=-g\frac{e}{2m_e}\vb{j}     
                & g\mu_B\sqrt{j(j+1)}     
                    &     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{landscape}
    \clearpage% Flush page
}
\end{document}
```

[image]